# spring boot starter gRPC test failed due to ServerInterceptor implementation

Tags: java, authorization, grpc, interceptor

I have a ServerInterceptor class in gRPC that is working as expected, but when I run other tests that make a request to the server they fail because they are not authorized, and that's fine because in the other test cases I'm not testing the security of the tests, those other tests are unrelated to the one I'm using the interceptor for.

The problem here is that the build of the app is interrupted. How can I add authorization to the other test cases so the build can continue?

This is the code for the interceptor:

```
public class GrpcServerRequestInterceptor implements ServerInterceptor {

        @Override
        public <ReqT, RespT> ServerCall.Listener<ReqT> interceptCall(
        ServerCall<ReqT, RespT> serverCall, Metadata metadata, ServerCallHandler<ReqT, 
        RespT> next) {

       log.info("Validating user token");
       var userToken = metadata.get(Metadata.Key.of("JWT", 
       Metadata.ASCII_STRING_MARSHALLER));
       validateUserToken(userToken);
       return next.startCall(serverCall, metadata);
    }

  private void validateUserToken(String userToken) {
    // Logic to validate token
  }
}
   



public class GrpcServerResponseInterceptor implements ServerInterceptor {
    
      @Override
      public <ReqT, RespT> ServerCall.Listener<ReqT> interceptCall(
          ServerCall<ReqT, RespT> serverCall, Metadata metadata, ServerCallHandler<ReqT, RespT> next) {
    
        return next.startCall(
            new ForwardingServerCall.SimpleForwardingServerCall<>(serverCall) {
              @Override
              public void sendMessage(RespT message) {
                log.info("Message being sent to client : " + message);
                super.sendMessage(message);
              }
            },
            metadata);
      }
    }
```

Comment: Just don't use the interceptor for the tests that you don't want authentication?